# validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get this work:

**Orders:**

```js
render () {
  const orders = this.state.orders.map((order, index) => <OrderRow order={order} key={index}/>);

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {orders}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

**OrderRow:**

```js
render () {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{this.props.order.number}</td>
      <td>{this.props.order.products}</td>
      <td>{this.props.order.shippingDate}</td>
      <td>{this.props.order.status}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

But still getting this error:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
See Orders > div > OrderRow > tr.
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: inside a table you cannot have a `div` in between any of these `table`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tr`, `td` . you can however have div's inside the `td` make sure your HTML follows this .

Comment: But where is this `<div>` inside of my code??

Comment: The error message says so. And even i cannot see a possible div in the above code. If this is the complete code then its weird.

Comment: Doesn't show up when I do it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9whLm5w/1/

Comment: No, it's working...

Comment: What is `this.state.orders`?

Comment: this is data fetched from the backend.

Comment: It appears that it was all fault of `webpack-dev-server`, when building with simple `webpack` command, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 40):

Wrap your `OrderRow` `<tr>` in `<tbody>` as explained in issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5652), Browsers need the `<tbody>` tag. If it is not in your code, then the browser will automatically insert it. This will work fine on first render, but when the table gets updated, then the DOM tree is different from what React expects. This can give strange bugs, therefore React warns you to insert the `<tbody>`.

**OrderRow**

```
render () {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{this.props.order.number}</td>
          <td>{this.props.order.products}</td>
          <td>{this.props.order.shippingDate}</td>
          <td>{this.props.order.status}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: he is wrapping his tr in a tbody. this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.orders.map((order, index) => {
          <tr index={index}>
            <td>{order.number}</td>
            <td>{order.products}</td>
            <td>{order.shippingDate}</td>
            <td>{order.status}</td>
          </tr>
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or more elegant:

```js
render () {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.orders.map((order, index) => (
          return (<OrderRow order={order} key={index} />);
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: It appears that it was all fault of webpack-dev-server, when building with simple webpack command, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It renders `tr` into `div`, so use `.map()` instead :)

Comment: It appears that it was all fault of webpack-dev-server, when building with simple webpack command, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something more automatic?

```
render() {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.orders.map((order, index) => {
          <tr index={index}>
            {Object.keys(order).map(function(key,id) {
              return (<td key={id}>{order[key]}</td>)
            })}
          </tr>
         }}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```