# validateDOMNesting(...): <p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this warning in the browser console:

On lines: 2 and 3

```
1. <Grid item xs={12} style={{  borderBottom: "1px solid #e4e4e4" }}>
2.   <div>
3.     <p className={classes.title}>Key Info</p>
4.   </div>
5. </Grid>
```

It's a React project. Also, I'm using webpack. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Jaya, check these answers so you'll see the reason why this happens, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112104/validatedomnesting-button-warning), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61341666/validatedomnesting-button-cannot-appear-as-a-descendant-of-button) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915629/validatedomnesting-tr-cannot-appear-as-a-child-of-div) can be a start

Comment: Its happening because either `Grid` is also `paragaph(<p>)`. That's why its giving warning `p` can't be child of `p`

Comment: What is `Grid`?